# Property IHtmlElementCollection.all broken by script tag in HTML file

Tags: delphi, ihtmldocument2

I am having a bit of trouble with IHtmlElementCollection used from Delphi XE2.  My document looks something like this, and I load it into TWebBrowser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test av skjema</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Header.js" ></script>      
  <style>
    body{ font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 9pt; }
    table{ background-color: silver; width=98%; }
   td{ background-color: white; vertical-align: top; padding: 2px; }
   .fullWidth{ width: 100%; border: 0px solid white; }
   .noFrame{ border: 0px solid white; overflow: hidden; width=100%; }
   .Header{ font-weight: bold; }
   .Question{ font-size: 9pt }
    .HelpText{ font-size: 8pt; color: navy; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
 ...
</form
</body>
</html>
```

When I try to iterate over all elements in the document using the IHtmlDocument2 interface, the "all" property will only contain the elements up to the script, for a total of 5 IHtmlElement objects.  After that, there are no more elements to find.

However, when I remove the tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Header.js" ></script>
```

the iterator will once again find all elements of the file, which is a great deal more.  Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Dunno, but just possibly the implementor of the interface doesn't expect the closing tag to be on the same line as the starting tag; or does not expect there to be nothing at all between the two tags. Try what happens when you add a couple of spaces between the tags and/or put the closing tag on a separate line.

Comment: maybe header.js contains an error causing HTML parsing to break? What's inside header.js?

Comment: The problem was that I processed the document too early, using OnDownloadComplete.  I should have used OnDocumentComplete, because the OnDownloadComplete  happens for every file that is downloaded as part of the document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting external content with TEmbeddedWB or TWebBrowser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637550/detecting-external-content-with-tembeddedwb-or-twebbrowser)