# Detecting external content with TEmbeddedWB or TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, c++builder, twebbrowser

I am trying to block anything external loaded by TEmbeddedWB or TWebBrowser (or TCppWebBrowser). I would like to block anything that is loaded from Internet including images, javascript, external CSS, external [embed] or [object] or [applet] or [frame] or [iframe], executing JavaScript that can load external content etc.

This problem consists of 2 parts:

- putting web browser into "restrict all" (except basic HTML without images) and detecting if such content exists
- if external content is not present ok, if it is, showing a "download bar" which after click puts web browser into "download all" mode and gets all content.

First item has issues. In TEmbeddedWB you can block almost anything using DownloadOptions switches and most important is ForceOffline switch but even with all of that turned off it still passes through some things like `[object]` or `[iframe]` tags. I know this is the case because I implemented OnBeforeNavigate2 event and it triggers for URLs contained in these tags and it also makes an entry in log of local server. Setting `OfflineMode` and `ForceOfflineMode` in TEmbeddedWB doesn't help for these items.

So how can I really block all?  So it needs to start as basic HTML with blocked external elements including scripts and CSS. Is there a way to trigger an event every time it wants to download anything so it can be blocked or avoiding triggering such event in the first place by blocking all external downloads? Do I need to fiddle with Internet Explorer zones and security? Any pointer in right direction would be helpful.

Second item is also tricky because I need to detect if problematic tags are present (such as "applet", "script", "link" etc. This detection doesn't need to be perfect but it must at least be good enough to cover most of such tags. I've done it like this:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Check for external content (images, scripts, ActiveX, frames...)
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
try
    {    
    bool                                HasExternalContent = false;
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLDocument2>     diDoc;                              // Smart pointer wrapper - should automatically call release() and do reference counting
    diDoc = TEmbeddedWB->Document;

    DelphiInterface<IHTMLElementCollection>     diColApplets;           DelphiInterface<IDispatch>          diDispApplets;      DelphiInterface<IHTMLObjectElement> diObj;
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLElementCollection>     diColEmbeds;            DelphiInterface<IDispatch>          diDispEmbeds;
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLFramesCollection2>     diColFrames;            DelphiInterface<IDispatch>          diDispFrames;
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLElementCollection>     diColImages;            DelphiInterface<IDispatch>          diDispImages;       DelphiInterface<IHTMLImgElement>    diImg;
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLElementCollection>     diColLinks;             DelphiInterface<IDispatch>          diDispLinks;
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLElementCollection>     diColPlugins;           DelphiInterface<IDispatch>          diDispPlugins;
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLElementCollection>     diColScripts;           DelphiInterface<IDispatch>          diDispScripts;
    DelphiInterface<IHTMLStyleSheetsCollection> diColStyleSheets;       DelphiInterface<IDispatch>          diDispStyleSheets;

    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_applets     (diColApplets));
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_embeds      (diColEmbeds));
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_frames      (diColFrames));
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_images      (diColImages));
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_links       (diColLinks));
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_plugins     (diColPlugins));
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_scripts     (diColScripts));
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_styleSheets (diColStyleSheets));

    // Scan for applets external links
    for (int i = 0; i < diColApplets->length; i++)
        {
        OleCheck(diColApplets->item(i,i,diDispApplets));
        if (diDispApplets != NULL)
            {
            diDispApplets->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLObjectElement, (void**)&diObj);
            if (diObj != NULL)
                {
                UnicodeString s1 = Sysutils::Trim(diObj->data),
                              s2 = Sysutils::Trim(diObj->codeBase),
                              s3 = Sysutils::Trim(diObj->classid);

                if (StartsText("http", s1) || StartsText("http", s2) || StartsText("http", s3))
                    {
                    HasExternalContent = true;
                    break;                                                  // At least 1 found, bar will be shown, no further search needed
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    // Scan for images external links
    for (int i = 0; i < diColImages->length; i++)
        {
        OleCheck(diColImages->item(i,i,diDispImages));
        if (diDispImages != NULL)                                           // Unnecessary? OleCheck throws exception if this applies?
            {
            diDispImages->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLImgElement, (void**)&diImg);
            if (diImg != NULL)
                {
                UnicodeString s1 = Sysutils::Trim(diImg->src);

                // Case insensitive check
                if (StartsText("http", s1))
                    {
                    HasExternalContent = true;
                    break;                                                  // At least 1 found, bar will be shown, no further search needed
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
catch (Exception &e)
    {
    // triggered by OleCheck
    ShowMessage(e.Message);
    }
```

Is there an easier way to scan this or the only one is to run several loops using other interface functions such as `Get_applets`, `Get_embeds`, `Get_stylesheets` etc. similar to code above? So far I found I'd have to call following functions to cover all of this:

```
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_applets     (diColApplets));
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_embeds      (diColEmbeds));
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_frames      (diColFrames));
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_images      (diColImages));
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_links       (diColLinks));
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_plugins     (diColPlugins));
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_scripts     (diColScripts));
    OleCheck(diDoc->Get_styleSheets (diColStyleSheets));
```

But I'd rather not implement that many loops if this can be handled easier. Can it?

Comment: Does the sentence *I would like to block anything that is loaded from Internet* mean you want to have offline mode ? If so, just set the `TWebBrowser.Offline` to True ;-)

Comment: It would be great if it were so easy. I set Offline and ForceOffline flags but it still loads some external content e.g. [object] tags or some frames.

Comment: How complicated your HTML is? Do you need Internet Explorer?

Comment: Yes, I need IE - HTML is not trivial. I though already about filtering HTML with RegEx and similar solutions. The problem is also that this is so terribly documented as well and examples are scarce (except if I want to go full C++ mode - then I have MSDN docs on that which are relatively detailed). The code above is result of tons of googling from various sources and I'm not even sure if it is correct with regards to memory leaks etc. although it works :)

Comment: other idea/option... you said IE... IE=IE, or IE=web browser? did you give a try to [TChromium](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/)?

Comment: Let's take that as last resort solution. IE control is working fine for these purposes and it also has something I'm not sure for Chromium - Edit mode. Not to mention market share etc. And I'm sure there are solutions or at least workarounds to block all downloads  so I'm not there yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you this solution:

```
#include "html.h"
THTMLDocument doc;
void __fastcall TForm1::CppWebBrowser1DocumentComplete(TObject *Sender, LPDISPATCH pDisp,
          Variant *URL)
{
    doc.documentFromVariant(CppWebBrowser1->Document);

    bool HasExternalContent = false;
    for (int i=0; i<doc.images.length; i++) {
        if(doc.images[i].src.SubString(1, 4) == "http")
        {
            HasExternalContent = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i=0; i<doc.applets.length; i++) {
        THTMLObjectElement obj = doc.applets[i];
        if(obj.data.SubString(1, 4) == "http")
            HasExternalContent = true;
        if(obj.codeBase.SubString(1, 4) == "http")
            HasExternalContent = true;
        if(obj.classid.SubString(1, 4) == "http")
            HasExternalContent = true;
    }
}
```

This great wrapper classes can be downloaded from [here](http://doxy.phphost.biz/html.rar).

Comment: This looks really useful. What is this wrapper for? There isn't much info on that site or in class itself.

Comment: This wapper writed by myself for applications which have html UI or any porpose related to HTML. with this wrapper also you can handle html events in C++ Builder such as "onmouseclick"; for more information see [this](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Editors_IDEs/C_CPP_CS/CPP_Builder/A_4378-C-Builder-and-Dynamic-HTML.html).